# How do I create an extract for a delta from the command line

Tags: jade-platform

I have a delta with some methods in it.
I want to create a schema extract that contains only the methods in the delta in an automated way so that I don't have to create one by hand or using the hateful selection tree in the Jade IDE.

The jadeworld documentation suggests I might be able to do it:
https://www.jadeworld.com/docs/jade-70/content/resources/userguide/chapter_10_-_extracting_and_loading_schemas/extracting_schemas_as_a_non-gui_client_application.htm

When I try, no extract files are created.

This is the command I am running:

```
 jadclient path=E:\Jade63\System\ schema=JadeSchema ini=C:\Jade63\bin\jade.ini app=JadeBatchExtract endJade File d:\temp\delta.scm d:\temp\delta.ddb d:\temp\param.unl delta=TFS3274
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could see if an error is logged in jommsg.log or another log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 'File' extracts, you need to specify which schema to extract.  This is the fourth parameter, after the UNL file, before adding the delta argument.  I've added this to the example below, assuming 'Delta' is the schema name.

```
jadclient path=E:\Jade63\System\ schema=JadeSchema ini=C:\Jade63\bin\jade.ini app=JadeBatchExtract endJade File d:\temp\delta.scm d:\temp\delta.ddb d:\temp\param.unl Delta delta=TFS3274
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if this will extract just the methods that are in the specified delta.  Rather, I believe everything specified by the UNL file will be extracted, but where any methods are checked out to a delta, the version in the specified delta will be extracted.

You'll need to experiment to confirm, but in my experience, patches are more suitable for performing extracts without needing to specify what's changed.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin's has answered the question I asked, I'm just adding this bit here for anyone else who happens this way. I was trying to automate creating a UNL file from a delta. The following perl script will generate a UNL file from a schema extract file. So you can create a schema extract from a delta in the IDE, then run this script on it to create a UNL, which you can then use for creating subsequent extracts.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$state="init";
$class="";
$method="";
@result=();
while(<>)
{
    if($state eq "init")
    {
        if(m/typeDefinitions/)
        {
            $state="inTypes";
        }
    }
    elsif($state eq "inTypes")
    {
        if(m/[^(]+\(\r/)
        {
            $state="inClass";
            ($class=$_) =~ s/\s*(\S+).*\(/$1/;
            $class =~ s/[\r\n]//g;
        }       
        elsif(m/inverseDefinitions/)
        {
            $state="done";
        }
    }
    elsif($state eq "inClass")
    {
        if(m/jadeMethodDefinitions/)
        {
            $state="inMethod";
        }
        elsif(m/^\s*\)\r/)
        {
            $state="inTypes";
        }

    }
    elsif($state eq "inMethod")
    {
        if(m/[^(]+[(]/)
        {
            ($method=$_) =~ s/\s*(\S+)\(.*/$1/;
            $method =~ s/[\r\n]//g;
            $state="inClass";
            push @result, "Method $class $method\n";
        }
    }   
}

@result = sort @result;
print @result;
print "\n";
```

Comment: I ran the script as follows, and it worked perfectly: `./create.pl extract.scm > extract.unl`